# What does "kiss the lunch box goodbye" mean?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, dr-strange-multiverse-of-madness

In *Doctor Strange in the Multiverse of Madness* (2022), Wanda and Doctor Strange speak about the powers that are possessed by America
Chavez:

> Wanda: She's a supernatural being. Such raw power could wreak  havoc
> on this and other worlds. Her sacrifice would be for the  greater
> good.
>
> Doctor Strange: Well, you can **kiss the lunch box goodbye**, 'cause  that's
> the kind of justification our enemies use.

What does "kiss the lunch box goodbye" mean?

Comment: I don't remember exactly but I'm sure there was a discussion earlier in the film about the Avengers having their faces put on lunch boxes.

Comment: @F1Krazy - Mentioned in Black Widow also

Comment: The idea is basically that Heroes are the ones that have merchandising about them, and if she's going to be morally grey, she isn't going to have her face plastered on any lunchboxes because nobody wants an actual real villain's merch. It's an informal metric for how good a person she is. Be the kind of person kids want on their lunchbox.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Part of this is explained by Strange's first use of the phrase. [From the transcript](https://movies.fandom.com/wiki/Doctor_Strange_in_the_Multiverse_of_Madness/Transcript)

> Strange: Well, he was right about both. We found a girl who can
> somehow travel across [the multiverse] but she's being pursued.
>
> Wanda: Pursued by who?
>
> Strange: Some kind of demon. One that covets her power for itself. Now
> we've taken her to Kamar-Taj, and... We've got our defenses, but... We
> could use an Avenger.
>
> Wanda: There are other Avengers.
>
> Strange: Yeah, but given a choice between the Archer with a mohawk,
> and several bug-themed crimefighters, or... One of the most powerful
> magic wielders on the planet, it's an easy call. Come to Kamar-Taj.
> **It'll get you back on a lunch box.**

Arno is right in that he's saying Wanda is proposing to do something evil, but there's a bit of nuance here that needs fleshing out.

#### Wanda's history

Wanda initially starts as a villain working for Hydra in *Avengers: Age of Ultron*. When

> Ultron decimates Sokovia, where Wanda is from, and kills her brother Quicksilver

she joins The Avengers, where she starts and cultivates a relationship with Vision. Wanda leaves The Avengers when Vision

> is killed by Thanos in *Avengers: Infinity War*. Vision is also not restored to life by the events of *Avengers: Endgame*.

Thus we wind up with Wanda more or less going off on her own and that's where the *Wandavision* series (which Strange is clearly not privy to) and, subsequently, this movie find her. All Doctor Strange knows at this point is that

1. Wanda was an Avenger but stopped running with them
2. He needs all the help he can get, and a former Avenger with known powers is a good place to start

#### Lunchboxes

So, let's talk lunchboxes for a second. Lunchboxes, for decades, have featured people like superheroes on them so that kids would be more likely to want to show them off at school (because showing off your underwear with superheroes on them is weird and scary). But why have a lunchbox with one superhero when you can have an entire team of them?

[image: Avengers Lunchbox]

That's [a real world lunchbox](https://www.superherostuff.com/marvel-avengers-thermos-insulated-lunch-box-1) by the way. You've got 5 superheroes on it

1. Captain America
2. Spider Man
3. Captain Marvel
4. Iron Man
5. Rocket Racoon

While not all of them are technically Avengers (3 out of 5 ain't bad), you get the idea. They all have at least worked together and are well-known heroes. Standard lunchbox fare.

Wanda is a minor player, so she wouldn't be likely to have her own lunchbox (fun fact: other than novelty stuff, real world luchboxes with just Wanda on them aren't really a thing). A team lunchbox would be the only way for someone lesser-known to be on one.

#### So what is Strange actually saying?

Strange is saying that he needs help, but he appeals to Wanda's desire to help people she's helped in the past. If Wanda were to help him, she could (at least ostensibly) be called an Avenger again. If she were an Avenger **she'd be eligible to be on an Avengers lunchbox**. Since she proposes an "ends justify the means" solution (usually the tell of a villain), Strange realizes that she won't be helping him or rejoining the Avengers, hence no lunchbox.

Comment: "3 out of 5 ain't bad" who apart from Rocket is the other non Avenger?

Comment: Yes, the Avengers are (in the MCU) named after Captain Marvel's Air Force nickname. But because she is offworld so much, she is technically not an official Avenger, although she works with them sometimes.

Comment: @WiggotheWookie In the MCU at least, Capt Marvel is more or less a solo actor. We can quibble about who belongs where, but my point is it's a "team" lunchbox

Comment: The short version is: Wanda has been very morally grey lately and coming and helping out Dr Strange will put her back firmly in Hero territory. The idea of being on a lunchbox is a kind of rubric for hero-ness. If you're someone people want on their Avengers-themed lunchboxes you must be doing something right.

Comment: But none of them are avengers there, the box clearly identifies them as THERMOS - True Heroes, Ever Ready, Masters Of Space.

Comment: It's only Wanda's history with the Avengers that makes this an Avengers thing. The lunch box status is just about being someone a 6 year old can be proud of. And someone that Thermos has a license agreement with.

Answer (score 36):

I believe this refers to superhero-branded lunch boxes that can be popular with primary-school children. Throughout the MCU we have seen occassional glimpses indicating that superhero merch is a thing in-universe (eg that boy with an Iron man replica helmet on).

Now these boxes are, crucially, super*hero*-branded. If Wanda turns evil, it would be inappropriate to sell Wanda-themed lunch boxes. [I believe there were references to the awkwardness of Captain America-branded stuff in the aftermath of "Civil War" somewhere.]

Fundamentally, what Dr Strange is saying here is "You sound like one of the bad guys."

Comment: You didn't even elaborate about lunchboxes, which is my main question.

Comment: @MichaelBevans: But... they did.

Comment: Actually, while Arno doesn't give any explicite references, he, at least, proves that Avenger merch is a thing, in-universe, and that Strange at the others weren't all breaking the fourth wall, talking to the audience about "our" merch. An even better answer would be if Machavity were to show that lunchboxes, and other merch, were in-universe and not a fourthwall break.